# Login doesn't work/stuck with Latest Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am running with an issue with using Facebook SDK(**4.9.1**) which opens in app browser for login if no system account present.

Login from system Facebook account works well. I am using the following code

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   manager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
   [manager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:controller handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                success(kFacebookStatusFailed);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                success(kFacebookStatusCancelled);
            } else {
                success(kFacebookStatusSuccess);
            }
}];
```

I have correctly done all required info.plist settings defined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started).

The problem is when it logs in using inapp browser, actually using **SafariViewController** found by debugging. It goes through all login process but in the end it stucks in a white blank screen and doesn't dismiss, see screenshot below

[image]

Have tried all possible steps but not able to get over it. But when I setup fresh project having nothing just the above login code and proper settings, all worked fine.

The only difference in the Fresh Project and Original Project is number of different frameworks used in the app, like **Crashlytics**, **Fabric**, **Instabug**, **Google Frameworks** etc. Is there any reason that I should suspect these framework that is causing problem, I think NO. So, what could be the problem, anyone who faced the same problem and can help me will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Is it worked for you somehow? I have the same problem...

Comment: @MariusKažemėkaitis No mate we couldn't solve this yet.. It seems there is  some setting we are missing, because it is not working in a specific application, but we couldn't make out what..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Add this to your AppDelegate:

In AppDelegate.m

1. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

   ```
   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   }
   ```
2. Add the following method to your AppDelegate.m:

   ```
   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
     return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
   }
   ```

I don't know if the `SafariViewController` checks for the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` but this worked for me. 
Give it a try. I hope it works for you.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: You need this import > #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>. And also I forgot to put the return YES inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (but this is implied :P)

Answer (score 2):

Yes There is a problem with Login

```
-(IBAction)fbAction:(id)sender

{

    FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
     manager.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        [manager logOut];
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
        
        [self fetchUserInfo];
    }
    else
    {
        [manager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Login process error");
             }
             else if (result.isCancelled)
             {
                 NSLog(@"User cancelled login");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Login Success");
                 if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
                 {
                     NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                     [self fetchUserInfo];
                     
                 }
             }
         }];
    }

}

-(void)fetchUserInfo

{

        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
        {
            NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
            
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, email"}]
             //[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"}]
             
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"results:%@",result);
                     
                     NSString *email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
                     NSString *userId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                     
                     if (email.length >0 )
                     {
                         
                         NSLog(@"email %@,userid %@",email,userId);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Facebook email is not verified");
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                 }
             }];
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Login will open in pop up.

Comment: Changing the FBSDKLoginManager loginBehavior to FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb worked for me. There was something broken with the new default SFSafariViewController-based method.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the `Branch` SDK installed and my `openURL:` app delegate methods were messed up.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary <NSString *, id> *)options
```

was only opening `Branch` links, while

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

was opening both `Facebook` and `Branch` links.

Double check that the logic in both methods (iOS9 and <=iOS8) are setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't "speak" objective C but you have to override OpenUrl.
Here is C#:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        // Facebook - We need to handle URLs by passing them to their own OpenUrl in order to make the SSO authentication works.
        return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
    }
```